# Desktop Configuration With Batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, registry, desktop, deepfreeze

Ok. So I'm trying to restore my desktop configuration from a registry file. I'm doing this because my school computer has a program called Deep Freeze. So I have a batch file that restores my network profiles.

Here's the code that is in the batch file for when the computer has just started:

```
ECHO SETTING UP DESKTOP CONFIGURATION...
REGEDIT /S DESKTOP.REG
TASKKILL /F /IM EXPLORER.EXE
START EXPLORER.EXE
ECHO DONE SETTING UP DESKTOP CONFIGURATION
TIMEOUT /T 5 >NUL /NOBREAK
```

Here's the code that is in the batch file for when the computer is going to save the desktop configuration before shutdown:

```
ECHO SAVING DESKTOP CONFIGURATION...
REGEDIT /E DESKTOP.REG "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop"
ECHO DONE SAVING DESKTOP CONFIGURATION
```

However, when I run the batch file that restores the desktop.. It doesn't revert to what was saved. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Maybe it's the wrong registry key I'm saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you described your situation, but i'm not able to find the actual **question**!? ;)

edit: You could use external tools to solve your problem. There are tiny tools around which can save and restore your desktop like pchell.com/support/savedesktoplayout.shtml

Comment: I see. The problem you're facing is probably caused by the type Windows itself reads the registry values. I think the explorer kill and restart does not trigger a _re-read_ of your registry value. It looks like windows only reads this key once at logon and stores it's values internally (memory or sth.)

I do not know about a method to force windows to read this key again.